# PHP Preg_match for a particular symbol

Tags: php, preg-match

How would you preg_match for the symbol combination |~| or %*|

```
$harms = 'i.e. flow of electricity in contact with person(s)dsn fds fsdnfsnd fsd fmnds f|~|mnsdf <br /><br />ajshajkhsjkahs|~|';
if(preg_match('#\|~\|#', $harms)) {
echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: Use backslashes for escaping regex meta characters (which are `|` and `*` in your case).

Comment: Post your complete `preg_match()` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape special chars in RegEx with a backslash `\`:

```
preg_match('#\|~\|#', $s);
preg_match('#%\*\|#', $s);
```

You could also use [`preg_quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape special chars:

```
preg_match('#'.preg_quote('|~|%*|','#').'#', $s);
```